# Firebase Error When Saving Multiple Topics

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I'm attempting to save multiple topics in Firebase. I can successfully save one at a time, but if I attempt to subscribe/unsubscribe from several topics in short time period, I get the following error:

```
<FIRMessaging/WARNING> Failed to subscribe to topic Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=5 "(null)"
```

Has anyone discovered a way to address this issue? From what I've read, the Firebase documentation says the calls to save Topics are asynchronous but plenty of users have also completed that, despite the calls being such, the topics aren't saved for their users when this error shows up.

edit: many other posts say a delay helps, but my subscriptions to Topics are triggered by button taps, so I can't coordinate the delays.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same error:`<FIRMessaging/WARNING> Failed to subscribe to topic Error Domain=com.google.fcm Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.fcm error 5.)"`

Comment: @Perrier unfortunately, no. I suspect that in most cases, the calls were still made. It just took a really long time for them to actually go through. I never spent enough time looking into it to know whether or not the majority did make it.